# Matlab checkbox gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface, checkbox

I have a checkbox on GUI that draws a rectangle on a live video feed, however, I need the rectangle to dissapear or be deleted when I uncheck it.
does anyone have any idea how to do this?

This is my code, I have tried putting things in else, but nothing works.

```
function Box(hObject,eventdata)

if (((get(hObject,'Value') == get(hObject,'Max'))))
 % Checkbox is checked-take appropriate action
 hold on;
rectangle('Position',[50,50,100,100],'EdgeColor','r')
else
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the handle created by the function rectangle. Then add this handle to the big handle of your GUI so that you are able to have access to it once the callback is called again.

So modify your function like so

```
function Box(hObject,eventdata,handles)

if (((get(hObject,'Value') == get(hObject,'Max'))))
 % Checkbox is checked-take appropriate action
 hold on;
handles.rectangleSave=rectangle('Position',[50,50,100,100],'EdgeColor','r');
guidata(handles.output,handles);
else
delete(handles.rectangleSave);
end
```

If you have never used handles, please have a look here :
http://www.matlabtips.com/on-handles-and-the-door-they-open/

handles.output usually stores the handle to the big interface window as explained here :
http://www.matlabtips.com/guide-me-in-the-guide/